# Whatsapp Web js , session is linked on whatsapp but I'm receiving QR code on initialzing client

Tags: whatsapp

[image]

[image]

Hello everyone,I'm trying to get all the sessions stored on database which are active on whatsapp and but when I try to basically start the sessions which are already authenticated but I'm receiving QR code doesn't make sense, how to solve this

(Note: the remote session is stored on the database I can see the files )

Whatsapp class

```
class WhatsappClient {
  constructor(id, store) {
    this.client = new Client({
      restartOnAuthFail: true,
      puppeteer: {
        headless: true,
        args: [
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
          '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
          '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
          '--no-first-run',
          '--no-zygote',
          '--disable-gpu',
        ],
      },
      authStrategy: new RemoteAuth({
        clientId: id,
        store: store,
        backupSyncIntervalMs: 400000,
      }),
    });
  }
```

The below Logic is to start the existing sessions that are stored in the database

```
const getAllSessions = await sessionsModel
    .find({
      status: 'connected',
      remoteSessionSaved: true,
      groupid: { $ne: null },
    })
    .lean();
  logger.info(
    `${JSON.stringify(getAllSessions)} all sessions to listen to `
  );
  let store;
  if (mongoStoreForWhatsappSessions[0]) {
    store = mongoStoreForWhatsappSessions[0];
  } else {
    store = new MongoStore({ mongoose });
  }

  getAllSessions.map(async (session) => {
    const { client } = new WhatsappClient(session?.id, store);
    client.on(QR, async (qr) => {
      logger.info('qr recieved the session is logged out ', session?.id);
      const sessionsUpdate = await sessionsModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          id: session?.id,
        },
        {
          loggedOutStatus: 'logout',
        }
      );
      client.destroy();
    });
    client.on(READY, async () => {
      logger.info(
        'Whatsapp is ready! for session and to store all the data',
        session?.id
      );
      const messagesSent = await getAllMessagesInfoAndStoreInDB(
        client,
        session?.groupid,
        session?.communityObjectId
      );
    });
    await client.initialize();
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tried out different things and I found out that you should make sure to not spawn the same whatsapp client when it is already spawned, and because of that it was automatically logging me out.

So I just added a check to make sure that if at all it is spawned then don't spawn it.

Comment: what? what did you mean? can you explain it?

Comment: Do not start the same bot with same credentials on the same server, if you do that then it will log you out automatically

Comment: @MohammedKhan If possible please share complete code

Comment: Hello @MohammedKhan can you share the code that helps you check this.